# Share record on basis of sharing of lookup object

Tags: apex, cpq, apex-managed-sharing

We have Quote object looking up to opportunity in our Org. We want to set  sharing of Quote object to Private. The sharing of the Quote record should be same as of opportunity. 
  We are planning to control it via apex sharing. Please let me how can I control the sharing of Quote record after it is created and related opportunity record sharing gets modified via manual sharing.

FYI - We cannot write trigger on OpportunityShare object.

Comment: Is quote standard Object or custom?

Comment: What have you tried to do? What options have you considered?

Comment: @pranay Jaiswal We can treat it as a custom object. Its actually a object from Salesforce CPQ manage package.

Comment: @Sebastian One option can be of a batch which we are thinking of. But a batch can't sink the access on quote in real time or atleast in few secs. It also gonna put extra load on the system as it need to be scheduled in few mins interval.